# join two ListVectorPlots

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have two ListVectorPlots, the are given below

```
ListVectorPlot[
 Table[{{x, y}, {4 Log[x],4 Log[y]}}, {x, -1.5, 1.5, 0.2}, {y, -2, 2, 
   0.2}]]

ListVectorPlot[
 Table[{{x, y}, {Log[x], Log[y]}}, {x, -1.5, 1.5, 0.2}, {y, -2, 2, 
   0.2}]]
```

They are identical, the only difference is the prefactor in front of the vector components.

I would like to show how the arrow-size of the second plot is smaller than the first plot. Is there a way to plot the two data sets in one, single plot such that it is apparent? Basically I am looking for a neat way of displaying the difference between the two data sets, which at the same time showing how they differ in magnitude.

Comment: It is very strange that `ListVectorPlot` forces data rescaling. From `VectorScale` doc: "When using an explicit *sfun*, positive values are automatically scaled to lie between 0 and 1. For other values the vector is not drawn."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p1 = ListVectorPlot[
  Table[{{x, y}, {4 Log[x], 4 Log[y]}}, {x, -1.5, 1.5, 0.2}, {y, -2, 
    2, 0.2}]]

p2 = ListVectorPlot[
  Table[{{x, y}, {Log[x], Log[y]}}, {x, -1.5, 1.5, 0.2}, {y, -2, 2, 
    0.2}], VectorStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.5], "Dart"}]

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]